# Generate Google Map from Addresses in Google Sheet

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, geocode

I'd like to create a Google Map that pulls addresses from a google sheet. I've figured out how to generate a map search of a single address (see below), but can't figure out how to get my map to plot multiple addresses.

```html
 function sendMap2() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary');
 var address = sheet.getRange('C15:C17').getValue();
 var mapUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=";
 var mapQuery = encodeURIComponent(address);
 GmailApp.sendEmail('emailaddress@gmail.com', 'Map', 'Map Link: '+mapUrl+mapQuery );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem:

You are using [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()), which will only return **the top-left cell** in the range you specify (that is, `C15`).

#### Solution:

If you want to get all the addresses in the range, you have to use [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) instead. This will return a two-dimensional array of values, which I'd suggest you to transform to a simple array of addresses. You can then iterate through each address in this array, appending each array to the body of the email message with [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat).

It could be something along the following lines:

```js
function sendMap2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary');
  var values = sheet.getRange('C15:C17').getValues();
  var addresses = [];  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    addresses = addresses.concat(values[i]);
  }
  var body = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < addresses.length; j++) {
    var mapUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=";
    var mapQuery = encodeURIComponent(addresses[j]);
    body = body.concat('Map Link: ' + mapUrl + mapQuery + '\n');
  }
  GmailApp.sendEmail('your-email', 'Map', body);
}
```

#### UPDATE:

If you want to point to several addresses in a single URL, you can use this instead:

```js
  var mapUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/";
  var body = 'Map Link: ' + mapUrl;
  for (var j = 0; j < addresses.length; j++) {
    var mapQuery = encodeURIComponent(addresses[j]);
    body = body.concat(mapQuery + '/');
  }
  GmailApp.sendEmail('your-email', 'Map', body);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Range.getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())
- [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [String.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely a step in the right direction! It pulls multiple addresses into maps, but it generates multiple map links, 1 link per map with 1 coordinate each. Is it possible to have all of the addresses map onto a single map rather than generate separate map links?

Comment: I think the only way of showing several different addresses is by having a route that will go through the different points. Is that what you want to have?

Comment: @taleesita I updated my answer based on your comment. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you @lamblichus! That plots them all on a single map with a route going through them, as you noted. Ideally, there wouldn't be a route on the map. I was hoping the plotted points would be saved to a google map list.

Comment: @taleesita I don't think this is currently possible in Maps. The only way to have the different addresses in a map is by having a route that goes through them, or creating a custom list, and this last one corresponds to a specific account. I think this is closest you can get.

Comment: In connection with the custom list - if we're ok with it corresponding to a specific account, is it possible to use a script to do that? I haven't found any that accomplish that, but I figured I'd ask since you raised it

Comment: @taleesita No, I don't think you can do this with the script.

Comment: Ah, bummer. Thank you for helping me tackle plotting multiple points, though! I'll "accept" your answer since it did indeed hit part of what I was trying to accomplish!